# How do dynamic backends start in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dynamic, google-cloud-datastore, backend

Can we start a dynamic backend programatically? mean while when a backend is starting how can i handle the request by falling back on the application(i mean app.appspot.com).

When i stop a backend manually in admin console, and send a request to it, its not starting "dynamically"

Answer (score 5):

> Dynamic backends come into existence when they receive a request, and
>   are turned down when idle; they are ideal for work that is
>   intermittent or driven by user activity.
>
> Resident backends run continuously, allowing you to rely on the state
>   of their memory over time and perform complex initialization.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html

I recently started executing a long running task on a dynamic backend and noticed a dramatic increase in the performance of the frontends. I assume this was because the long running task was competing for resources with normal user requests.

Comment: "Dynamic backends come into existence when they receive a request" - how do you send a request to a backend?

Comment: Well, I think they have endpoints (from what I remember) like `backendname.appname.appspot.com`.

Answer (score 4):

Backends are documented quite thoroughly [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/). Backends have to be started and stopped with appcfg or the admin console, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Commands). A stopped backend will not handle requests - if you want this, you should probably be using the Task Queue instead.

Comment: "a stopped backend will not handle requests" this is what i need. the start, stop states of a dynamic backend shown in the admin console are not the correct representations of its state. just "start" a dynamic backend in the admin console, for it to handle requests dynamically, it wont charge you if there are no requests.

Comment: @RemotePath Then you want Task Queues, not backends. This is exactly how task queues work.

Comment: You can combine Task Queues and backends like this:

`taskqueue.add(url='/task_url', method='GET', target='name_of_your_backend'))`

The task will not run on dev though, so set target to None on dev:

`taskqueue.add(url='/task_url', method='GET', target=(None if const.DEBUG else 'name_of_your_backend'))`

Where DEBUG is equal to `os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Dev')`

Comment: @crizCraig There's a `get_url` method in the backends API that allows you to avoid that sort of special-case code - it returns the right answer for prod and dev. My point was, though, that if you want to start and stop backends programmatically, you should probably be using task queues instead.

Comment: @Nick Cool, thanks! Also thanks for all your great answers on stackoverflow! I'm always on the look out for Nick Johnson stuff :) Also, thanks for the great service in GAE. I looooove Google App Engine! :D

Comment: @Nick Johnson Wouldn't I need the backend name, not the URL for the target parameter?

Comment: @crizCraig There are methods for that too, in the same module.

Comment: @NickJohnson Do I need to use appcfy again to start a dynamic backends  after each time it has been shutdown automatically by itself?

Comment: @lucemia No, dynamic backends will start and stop as needed.

Comment: @NickJohnson Thanks your reply! That's really help me a lot. Just want to make thing more clear, while you mentioned "The dynamic backends will start and stop as needed." The "dynamic backend stop as needed" is different to "stop the backend by appcfg or backend admin console", isn't it?

Comment: @lucemia The whole point of dynamic backends is that they're dynamic - they start when there's traffic that needs serving, and stop when they're idle for a while.

Comment: @NickJohnson The get url method is not good if the backend execution takes a long time. The request responce times out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a dynamic backend need not be explicitly stopped.  The overvicew (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html) states that the billing for a dynamic backend stops 15 minutes after the last request is processed.  So, if your app has a cron job, for example, that requires 5 minutes to complete, and needs to run every hour, then you could configure a backend to do this.  The cost you'll incur is 15+5 minutes every hour, or 8 hours for the whole day.  I suppose the free quota allows you 9 backend hours.  So, this type of scenario would be free for you.  The backend will start when you send your first request to it through a queue, and will stop 15 minutes after the last request you send is processed completely.