# Starting and stopping Google App Engine backends

Tags: google-app-engine, backend

I read the Google App Engine backend docs, but I still can't understand how to start/stop backends (dynamic backends) from Python (using URLFetch, I guess).

Could someone give me a code example? The backend will not be on the application's default version.

Comment: This question (and answer) had similar content but without the code example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252337/how-do-dynamic-backends-start-in-google-app-engine

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of backend you are using, "Resident Backends" can't be shutdown from the production environment only via the Admin Console or command-line while "Dynamic Backends" are shutdown after sitting idle for a few minutes.

So if you use Dynamic Backends you can just send a request telling it to stop what it is doing and it will be shutdown automatically.

http://code.google.com/intl/iw/appengine/docs/python/config/backends.html#Types_of_Backends

***Edit***

Example of how this might work:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import time

class ShutdownHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        memcache.put('backendShutdown', True, 60)

class StartHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        lastCheck = time.time()
        while True:
            if time.time() - 60 > lastCheck:
                stopBackend = memcache.get('backendShutdown')
                if stopBackend:
                    memcache.delete('backendShutdown')
                    break
                lastCheck = time.time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _handlers = [(r'/_ah/start', StartHandler),
                 (r'/backend/worker/shutdown', ShutdownHandler)] # somekind of handler for shutdown
    run_wsgi_app(webapp.WSGIApplication(_handlers))
```

And to stop it you would use:

```
from google.appengine.api import backends, urlfetch
url = backends.get_url('worker') + '/backend/worker/shutdown'
urlfetch.fetch(url)
```

Comment: I did read the docs, but could you please give me a code example, than can be run on the production environment, and can start/stop backends? Let's say my backend is called "worker" and my app is called "sampleapp", how would I start/stop my dynamic backend?

Comment: If the example above doesn't work then you could try setting a variable inside the worker and do the same without the memcache.

Comment: Using memcache is a bad idea here. It's a cache, you shouldn't use it for reliable storage.

Comment: I think that the cache should be able to keep a value for atleast 60 seconds, no?

Comment: No, the cache doesn't even guarantee how long, or even if, an item will be stored.

Answer (score 3):

Use `appcfg` to start and stop backends. From [the documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Backend_States):

> `appcfg backends <dir> start <backend>`
>
> Sets the backend state to START, allowing it to receive HTTP requests.
>   Resident backends start immediately. Dynamic backends do not start
>   until the first user request arrives. Has no effect if the backend was
>   already started.
>
> `appcfg backends <dir> stop <backend>`
>
> Sets the backend state to STOP and shuts down any running instances.
>   The stopped backend cannot receive HTTP requests; if it recevies a
>   request, it returns a 404 response. This command has no effect if the
>   backend was already stopped.

Comment: Isn't there any way to start it from my code? I don't think there's any way to do appcfg.py backends ... from the production environment itself.