# Starting and stopping Google App Engine backends in java using eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using backend to process some task, which takes 3 minutes on a 2.4 ghz processor.
In backends the process consumes shows 8 hours consumed with B8 instance.
I just want to stop after it finished the processing. Could you explain how to stop a backend in Java after it has been processed.

Comment: refer this already asked question  [this][1] it should help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221638/starting-and-stopping-google-app-engine-backends

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer probably:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Shutdown