# Shutting down dynamic backend instance in google app engine(python) by sending http request or code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I have created a dynamic backend instance with backend.yaml file . Now i wants some way that it can shutdown after the request is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backends are deprecated.  You want to switch to Modules.  You can use the idle_timeout parameter to have an instance shutdown after a preferred time of idleness:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: can you give any example how to define backends.yaml with idle_timeout parameter.

Comment: You do not use backends.yaml. You set up a separate yaml file for your backend.  It is in the docs in the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic backend supposed to be shut after some idle time. But still if you want to shut it down, you can send a request to stop it. You can get code example from following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224387/2594162

Comment: what is the default idle time for shutting instance down??